# what does this strange little yellow arrow below the command prompt mean?

Tags: bash, rbenv

I am installing rbenv, following their documentation to

add ~/.rbenv/bin to your $PATH for access to the rbenv command-line utility.  And this arrow shows up.  What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: You have a stray double quote at the end of `$PATH`. The arrow is telling you it's waiting for more input for you to finish the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly your `PS2` prompt, used for line continuation. For example, I have `PS1` set to `'pax> '` and `PS2` set to `'...> '` and the following transcript shows that in action:

```
pax> echo 'hello
...> there'
hello
there
```

The *reason* the `PS2` prompt is there is because you have an unterminated `"` character (though, technically, this is an *unstarted* quote but the shell isn't smart enough to realise that and the effect is the same).

I suggest you try something like:

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile
```

You'll notice I'm using *single* quotes there as well since you probably want the *literal* strings `$HOME` and `$PATH` being placed in your profile rather than their current interpreted values.

---

And, one other thing, there are certain classes of profiles that will "break" if you just blindly append stuff to the end.

It's fine for profiles that are simple sequential beasts (ones that run cleanly from top to bottom) but, if you have something with a lot of control structures (like `if` statements), you should be investigating the *best* place to put it in the file.

By that I mean a profile containing (the admittedly contrived):

```
# Don't do rest of file in first two weeks of a month.
if [[ $(date +%d) -le 14 ]]; then
    exit
fi
```

may incorrectly skip your changes if you just add them to the file end without analysis. In this case, the best place is probably immediately *above* that `if` statement.

Comment: did you mean to move the single quote before $HOME? like this: 
    `echo export PATH='$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Nick: no. The intent here seems to be to output the entire line (without interpretation) to your profile. IMO, that's better indicated by quoting the complete line itself. It will _work_ the way you suggest until the line you want to output is `<tab>export<7 spaces>PATH='$HOME...'` at which point your carefully crafted spacing will disappear :-)